# Save multiple UISwitch states

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Ive been trying to save the `UISwitch` state for multiple switches within my `grocery.m` file so when the user terminates the app the state of the switches would remain as they were. This is how I've done it so far but have not had any luck. I think the issue has to do within my `grocery.m` file and not the `appDelegate.m`. If anyone can tell me where my mistake is, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 


NSUserDefaults* defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    

push.switchstore1.on = [defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch1"];
push.switchstore2.on = [defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch2"];
push.switchstore3.on = [defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch3"];

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app]; //Listener
    }

 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {



NSUserDefaults* defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool: push.store1.on forKey: @"mySwitch1"];
[defaults setBool: push.store2.on forKey: @"mySwitch2"];
[defaults setBool: push.store3.on forKey: @"mySwitch3"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[self saveContext]; //Already in the method by default
}
```

**WITHIN GROCERY.M**

```
  -(void) viewDidLoad
 { 
 NSUserDefaults* defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 switchStore1.on = [defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch1"];
 switchStore2.on = [defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch2"];
 switchStore3.on = [defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch3"];
 }
```

**EDIT what has been added to delegate.h (property has also been synthesized in .m)**

```
groceryViewController *push;
@property (nonatomic, retain) groceryViewController *push;
```

Comment: You seem to be allocating two different objects and checking the bools in each instance instead of going with one object.  Also, since iOS 4.x, applicationWillTerminate is hardly ever called.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks so how do you suggest I do this? I declared it once now (made the change) but still no luck

Comment: Remove one of the alloc's. It may be a property, but that's where you're going wrong here.

Comment: I did this as the user below suggested. Put in the .h file and as a property. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Maybe an NSLog() would shed some light on the situation.

Comment: Sorry if this is extremely obvious but where and what should I NSLog?

Comment: Put one of these at the end of every method `NSLog([defaults boolForKey: @"mySwitch1"] : @"YES" ? @"NO");` and use three of them, one for each default.  Compare them.

Answer (score 0):

In your applicationWillTerminate, you're initiating a brand new groceryViewController, which will always have the default "off" values for the switches. You need to use the same groceryViewController that was instantiated in the app's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. There are various ways to do this, including using a global variable or using a property in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Will give that a try immediately and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: It did not work. I declared it in my .h file and as a property

Comment: You need to update your original post with the new code you're using. It's hard to tell exactly what you've done.

Comment: You don't show how you're actually using "push". Sorry, your code seems a bit chaotic at this point, and it's hard to pinpoint exactly what could be wrong. Where and how do you use "push"?

Comment: push.store1.on push.store2.on etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You are always creating a new instance of `groceryViewController`, so that will not refer to same memory location from where you want to capture the information.